OpenJDK Java17 ZGC garbage collector won't use more than 20% of allocated ram
I have a very high throughput microservice running in AWS in ECS using OpenJDK Java17.  I'm testing with ZGC moving from G1GC and I notice that ZGC will not use the full allocated heap (10g), only 20% of it (2g).  Which causes the CPU to be at 100% and looking at the gc logs I see a lot of Allocation Stall.  With G1GC with similar options it will use 8g and spike to 10g under heavy load but won't crash and will recover.  ZGC will eventually crash and exit.
Here's my options:
-Xms10g
-Xmx10g
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0
-XX:+UseZGC
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=32
-XX:ConcGCThreads=16

If I run java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal I see that MaxRAMPercentage ignored my 80% I set and uses the default and I haven't been able to change it.
double MaxRAMPercentage                         = 25.000000                                 {product} {default}

I can't get it to use more than 2g. Thanks in advance.

There’s no point in specifying MaxRAMPercentage and Xmx at the same time. The former does not do what you seem to think it does.

Both down-votes seem inapplicable here. (a) No debugging info needed. And (b) all necessary details are provided, written clearly. I give this Question my up-vote.

Well, I didn’t downvote but the information does not seem to be complete. When I pass the options specified in the question to Java 17, I get double MaxRAMPercentage                         = 80.000000 as expected. Not that it matters though, as the heap size has been fixed to 10G anyway.

@Holger thanks for testing it out.  I am using MaxRAMPercentage incorrectly and have removed it.  But the GC spends 10% of the CPU which is just crazy high.  I need to find the right combination of settings.  But G1GC was much easier to tune.

Not every GC is suitable for every application. Since you apparently also want to use -XX:+UseStringDeduplication which ZGC does not support in Java 17 (it has been added in Java 18), the most obvious solution would be to stay with G1GC.

As commented by Holger, you may have misunderstood the purposes of those two parameters.
They both control the size of the Java heap. One works by percentage while the other sets a specific amount. Do not use both together.
See reference material at foojay.io or its data source ChrisWhoCodes.



MaxRAMPercentage
mx




Maximum percentage of real memory used for maximum heap size
set maximum Java heap size



Related:

VM options for modern JVMs and JDKs
What are the -Xms and -Xmx parameters when starting JVM?
Changing maximum java heap size

